# writing to a file via FTP in python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

So i've followed the docs on this page:
http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary

And maybe i'm confused just as to what 'retrbinary' does...i'm thinking it retrives a binary file and from there i can open it and write out to that file.

here's the line that is giving me problems...

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR temp.txt',open('temp.txt','wb').write)
```

what i don't understand is i'd like to write out to temp.txt, so i was trying

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR temp.txt',open('temp.txt','wb').write('some new txt'))
```

but i was getting errors, i'm able to make a FTP connection, do pwd(), cwd(), rename(), etc.

p.s. i'm trying to google this as much as possible, thanks!

Comment: "retrives a binary file and from there i can open it and write out to that file" Isn't very clear.  Could you expand on this with a step-by-step list of what you want to do?  From the comments, it's perfectly unclear what you want to do and what problem you're having with ftplib.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the original code should have worked, *if you were trying to download a file from the server*. The `retrbinary` command accepts a function object you specify (that is, the name of the function with no `()` after it); it is called whenever a piece of data (a binary file) arrives. In this case, it will call the `write` method of the file you `open`ed. This is slightly different than `retrlines`, because `retrlines` will assume the data is a text file, and will convert newline characters appropriately (but corrupt, say, images).

With further reading it looks like you're trying to write to a file on the server. In that case, you'll need to pass a file object (or some other object with a `read` method that behaves like a file) to be called by the store function:

```
ftp.storbinary("STOR test.txt", open("file_on_my_computer.txt", "rb"))
```

Comment: yes i am trying to write to a file on the server, but now that i think of it that may be the wrong way to go...rather i should just create the file locally then send/upload the file once it has been written/created, this way it should minizie the connection time.

Comment: That would be the easiest way to write to a file on the server. Initially, I thought you were trying to download a file from the server. I've updated my answer to clarify what the code you have (in the first block) actually does.

Answer (score 0):

ftp.retrbinary takes second argument as callback function
it can be directly write method of file object i.e.open('temp.txt','wb').write
but instead you are calling write directly

you may supply your own callback and do whatever you want to do with data

```
def mywriter(data):
    print data
ftp.retrbinary('RETR temp.txt', mywriter)
```